# SQL three table join help - customers without orders in dates

Tags: mysql, join

I have the (drastically simplified) schema of three tables as follows:

[image]

I'm looking to query the database for customers without orders in a certain date range. I know `LEFT JOIN` can be used to simply find customers with no invoices etc., but I am unsure how I can leverage `JOIN` (or perhaps even `OUTER JOIN`) to introduce a date range.

Is this possible using SQL JOIN or should I be looking to use `NOT IN` syntax to find customers that aren't in a given result set?

My database software is MySQL.

Comment: _My database software is MySQL_... so why tag it with [sql-server]?

Comment: @Tanner apologies, I simply selected all of the suggested tags. I should have been more vigilant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select c.*
from customers c left join
     invoices i
     on c.code = i.customer_code and
        i.date between DATE1 and DATE2
where i.customer_code is null;
```

The key idea is to put the date range in the `on` clause.

Comment: @McAdam331 . . . No, it would not.  It would turn the join into an inner join.

Comment: Thanks! This does the job. Now I just need to expand it to provide month by month data, e.g to find customers who may have stopped ordering in certain months.